# What is meaning of Below code?

Tags: magento2

$block = $this->_layout->getBlock('google_analytics');

Answer (score 0):

In simplest terms is following is your block

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
       name="some.layout.example"
       template="Vendor_Module::example.phtml" />
```

then in any other block you can render this block by

```
 $this->_layout->getBlock('some.layout.example');
```

In short it is a kind of shortcut used to render blocks/templates/sections in other blocks.